# Mono, Owin: error response is cut off to 2048 bytes

Tags: c#, mono, signalr, owin, katana

I use self-hosting SignalR (version 2.1.1) application for Mono (version 3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1)). I want to include error page for Owin in my project. I use UseErrorPage extension method from  Microsoft.Owin.Diagnostics (http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/getting-started-with-owin-and-katana). Here my Startup class:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace SignalR.Namespace 
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseErrorPage(ErrorPageOptions.ShowAll);

            app.Map("/signalr", map =>
            {
                map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
                {
                    EnableDetailedErrors = true
                };
                map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I suppose that if I will meet some error then I can see this in my browser.
It works fine in .NET, but there is some trouble in Mono. HTTP response with HTML-error is cut off to 2048 bytes. So I can see only first 2K of error page in browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Internal Server Error</title>
    <style>
        body {
font-family: 'Segoe UI',Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size: .813em;
line-height: 1.4em;
color: #222;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
/*font-family: 'Segoe UI',Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;*/
font-weight: 100;
}

h1 {
color: #44525e;
margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
}

h2 {
margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
}

h3 {
color: #363636;
margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

code {
font-family: consolas, "Courier New", courier, monospace;
}

body .titleerror {
padding: 3px;
}

body .location {
margin: 3px 0 10px 30px;
}

#header {
font-size: 18px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
border-top: 1px #ddd solid;
border-bottom: 1px #ddd solid;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#header li {
display: inline;
margin: 5px;
padding: 5px;
color: #a0a0a0;
}

#header li:hover {
background: #A9E4F9;
color: #fff;
}

#header li.selected {
background: #44C5F2;
color: #fff;
}

#stackpage ul {
list-style: none;
padding-left: 0;
margin: 0;
/*border-bottom: 1px #ddd solid;*/
}

#stackpage .stackerror {
padding: 5px;
border-bottom: 1px #ddd solid;
}

#stackpage .stackerror:hover {
background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

#stackpage .frame:hover {
background-color: #f0f0f0;
text-decoration: none;
}

#stackpage .frame {
padding: 2px;
margin: 0 0 0 30px;
border-bottom: 1px #ddd solid;
}

#stackpage .frame h3 {
padding: 5px;
margin: 0;
}

#stackpage .source {
padding: 0px;
}

#stackpage .source ol li {
font-family: consolas, "Courier New", courier, monospace;
white-space: pre;
}

#stackpage .source ol.highlight li {
/*color: #e22;*/
/*font-weight: bold;
```

It is reproduced with latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, IE. Which reason of so strange behaviour of Owin with Mono?